# Spring REST call gives 302 redirect

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am using angularjs to make a REST call to my tomcat backend managed by Spring.  But my server code never seems to get the call and the browser gets a 302 with "index.html" appended at the end of the url.  For example, if my initial call was "localhost:8080/api/search/someString", browser receives a 302 redirect to "localhost:8080/api/search/someString/index.html", which then redirects to "localhost:8080/api/search/someString/index.html/index.html".

This keeps happening until a "Too many redirects" error occurs and it fails.  Any ideas anyone?

Here is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/page/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Angular call:

```
search: function (searchStr) {
        return $http.get("/api/search/"+searchStr);
    }
```

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class SearchResource {

@Autowired
private ItemService itemService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/search/{searchStr}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Item> getItemsBasedOnSearchString(@PathVariable String searchStr)     {
    return itemService.getAllItems();
}

public ItemService getItemService() {
    return itemService;
}

public void setItemService(ItemService itemService) {
    this.itemService = itemService;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you can make the stupidest of mistakes!  I changed the RequestMapping annotation from "/api/search" to "/search" and it works.

Thanks.